# IntelliJ regex, to find and replace across files, is not replacing the multiple word match with a backreference

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJIdea community addition search and replace across files dialog for executing the regex below.
I'm working on cleaning up a java project has recently moved to Java 11, and I would like to replace the following java code 
`= new Integer(varname);`
where varname can be a variable name or a literal int, and then replace the whole match and end up with the following 
 
`= varname;` 
I tried to use IntelliJ find and replace across files using regex and came up with the following 
`new\sInteger\(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\)`
Which seems to work, it gives the right results, but when I try to use the back reference like 
`$1` 
I actually get 
`= new varname;` 
where I would have expected the 'new ' keyword and space to have been overwritten as well as the 'Integer('

I have trawled through the answers to similar questions and experimented with grouping and boundaries all to no avail, can anyone help to remove the 'new ' characters? .

Comment: It looks like you are not describing your actual case because `new\sInteger\(([a-zA-Z0-9])\)` wouldn't be able to match `varname` as `([a-zA-Z0-9])` can match only *single* character (at least in standard regex engine, I am not sure how Intellij executes it).

Comment: Aside from that Integer class has constructor accepting String (although it is deprecated, it is still possible to use it). So be careful with cases like `String var = "1"; Object obj = new Integer(var);`.

Comment: good spot , it is actually returning me matches with single literals or single char var names.

Comment: @Pshemo I'm actually trying to remove the deprecated messages from the code scanning tools that run as part of our build.

Comment: To solve that you would need `new\sInteger\(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\)`, but still there is a problem with accepting strings as arguments. OR what about accepting expressions like `new Integer(foo() + bar())`? Regex may not be best tool to handle that (and I am not sure what tool is so can't help you with that...)

Comment: @Pshemo luckily it's mostly all test code , but thanks for your warnings

Comment: Anyway I can't reproduce problem described in question. When I use `new\sInteger\(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\)` and replace it only with `$1` `new Integer(var)` becomes `var` (without `new ` part).